# How do I implement a UITableView that can scroll over a background

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a tableview where the tableview cells can scroll over a background similar to the way the facebook Poke app works. Are they using a custom uitableview or implementing the interface with a uicollectionview?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `UIImageView` with your background image. Then set the table view's `backgroundView` property to the image view. This approach works well with a plain style table.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the table view and the cells a clear background color (in IB or code), and give the window a background color -- you can use colorWithPatternImage:, if you want an image in the background.